# Member templates and inheritance

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance

Please consider the following program:

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
struct A {
    virtual void f(const T &) {
        std::cout << "A::f(const T &)" << std::endl;
    }
};

template <typename T>
struct B : A<T> {
    template <typename U>
    void f(const U &) override {
        std::cout << "B::f(const U &)" << std::endl;
    }
};

int main() {
    B<int> *b = new B<int>;
    A<int> *a = b;
    a->f(42);
    b->f(42);
}
```

Compile and execute with:

```
g++ -std=c++11 test.cpp -o test &&
./test
```

The output is:

```
A::f(const T &)
B::f(const U &)
```

The output proves that `B::f` does not override `A::f`, even if the `override` keyword is accepted by `g++` (I consider this is a bug).

Although, `clang++` does not accept `override` here:

```
$ clang++ -std=c++11 test.cpp -o test && ./test
test.cpp:13:23: error: only virtual member functions can be marked 'override'
    void f(const U &) override {
                      ^~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
```

If I add a member `B::f` that *really* overrides `A::f`, the output is:

```
B::f(const T &)
B::f(const T &)
```

But how to call `template <typename U> B::f(const & U)` from that overriden implementation:

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
struct A {
    virtual void f(const T &) {
        std::cout << "A::f(const T &)" << std::endl;
    }
};

template <typename T>
struct B : A<T> {
    void f(const T &) override {
        std::cout << "B::f(const T &)" << std::endl;
        // how to call template <typename U> f(const U &) from here?
    }

    template <typename U>
    void f(const U &) {
        std::cout << "B::f(const U &)" << std::endl;
    }
};

int main() {
    B<int> *b = new B<int>;
    A<int> *a = b;
    a->f(42);
    b->f(42);
}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call the member function template (or rather: the member function made from it) explicitly like this:

```
void f(const T &x) override {
    f<T>(x);
}
```

Comment: Of course! Thank you. I was misled by the fact that both methods used exactly one template parameter, so I first thought that `f<T>(…)` would lead to infinite recursion.